# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el tipo de moneda de un sitio web que esta en un host?

Tags: php, hosting

El sitio web ya lo he subido al hosting HostGator, sin embargo, cuando hago mis pruebas locales, me salen los precios en moneda mexicana (soy residente mexicana y me interesa que en esa moneda este el sitio), sin embargo, al momento de subirlo al Host me cambia la moneda a dolares, me parece que es porque el sitio se adapta al host en donde este alojado.

Mi duda es si hay manera de poder convertirla a moneda mexicana.

Así se ve el sitio de manera local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sitio de forma remota:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pregunte en el curso de Udemy, pero solo me dijeron que agregara estas lineas de código para su conversión:

```
$cambioDivisa = file_get_contents("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q=USD_".$value->price_detail->currency."&compact=y");
                                        
$cambioDivisaJson = json_decode($cambioDivisa, true);
                                                                                
$valorUSD = $cambioDivisaJson["USD_".$value->price_detail->currency]["val"]*$value->price_detail->amount;
                                                                                
echo '<h4 class="float-left precioFinal"><span>$ '.$valorUSD.'</span></h4><br>';
```

Y al agregarlas, no me aparecen los precios...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan auxiliar, muchas gracias y saludos.

Comment: Has probado establecer la información del localismo con `setlocale`: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php

Comment: Prueba con esto al principio del script: **`setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_MX');`**

Comment: Hola que tal, no me funciono =( quise utilizar esta página https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/ , es la que coloque arriba en el código pero no me convierte nada =(

Comment: No la he usado nunca dicha api, podrías probar también usar `money_format()` de PHP, da formato a un número como un string de moneda: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 0):

te paso lo que encontré como solución al requerimiento y la explicación de como llegue a esto.

En primer lugar https://www.currencyconverterapi.com/ es una pagina que ofrece una API que brinda en línea la tasa de cambio de diferentes monedas en el mundo.

Para utilizarla, debes primero crearte una cuenta. Existe un modelo free que, segun indican no tiene un servicio constante o garantizado, pero funciona. La cuenta la creas aqui ([link](https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/free-api-key)). Debes poner tu email y te enviará a tu casilla algo como lo que sigue:

Hi,
Before you can use the API key, you need to verify your email. Click here to verify.

Here's your free API key: b8ec8e3ce30769643cAA

Example usage:
https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=USD_PHP&compact=ultra&apiKey=b8ec8e3ce30769643cAA

Best regards,
Manny

El ejemplo de uso te permite convertir USD a Pesos filipinos. Estimo que no es lo que buscas, pero podes hacer click en este [link](https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/currencies?apiKey=do-not-use-this-key) y obtener los diferentes códigos de conversión. Si es USD a MXN, el código quedaría como USD_MXN.

Hasta acá solo solucionamos lo primero. Importante: en el mail anterior, cambie la API y así no va a funcionar, pero si pones tu clave funcionará perfecto.

A continuación te dejo el código que reemplaza el que enviaste. Debes ajustar los datos de llamado a clase y demás... pero lo dejé como variable expuesta. Estoy suponiendo que la conversión es desde USD a pesos Argentinos (ARS). Puedes cambiar eso.

```
<?php  
$conversion = 'USD_ARS';
$precio_en_usd = 10;
$key = 'b8ec8e3ce30769643cAA';

$cambioDivisa = file_get_contents("https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=".$conversion."&compact=ultra&apiKey=".$key);

$cambioDivisaJson = json_decode($cambioDivisa, true);

$valorUSD = $cambioDivisaJson[$conversion]*$precio_en_usd;

echo '<h4 class="float-left precioFinal"><span>$ '.$valorUSD.'</span></h4><br>';

?>
```

Ojala esta info te sea de utilidad.

Agrego info: si quieres usar codigo PHP directo, la misma pagina te ofrece un ejemplo en https://www.currencyconverterapi.com/docs/sample-code/php

Comment: Hola que tal, he hecho lo que me has dicho, por lo menos ya no me aparece $0, pero me aparecen todos los precios en $203.78296, me podrías auxiliar? Al código que me has enviado cambie el valor de `$conversion = 'USD_ARS';` por `$conversion = 'USD_MXN';` y el valor de la variable `$key`

Comment: consulta... los valores originales son USD y los quieres en mexicanos verdad? fijate si este link te entrega el JSON en un navegador de la tasa de conversión de 1USD a MXN: https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=USD_MXN&compact=ultra&apiKey=[AGREGA KEY]

Comment: Así es, cuando los subo al host se colocan los valores en USD, los valores son extraídos de una API de Udemy, pero me imagino que por el host que utilizo los valores se muestran en USD

Comment: $203.78296, se refiere a 203 MXN con .87296 decimales!.. .si necesitas mostrar menos decimales podes utilizar round(203.78296, 2); lo cual generará 203.78

Comment: Así es, mi duda era porque los precios no son los mismos, hay unos que cuestan MX$500 y otros MX$323 por decir un ejemplo... Y ahora todos aparecen con $203.78296

Comment: A ver, esa API **es de pago**. ¿Estás dispuesta a pagar por ella? ¿Tu problema es que quieres convertir o que quieres cambiar divisas? Son dos cosas totalmente distintas y no queda explicado con claridad en la pregunta.

Comment: 323MX$ son 15.84USD. Lo que la API devuelve cuando la llamas es la tasa de conversión, o sea 20.384. De manera que si tienes 15.84 x 20.384 = 323. Lo único que necesitas es variabilizar cada precio y multiplicarlo por lo que traiga la api y luego ajustar los decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Solución sencilla: usa al inicio de cada archivo en que lo necesites:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_MX');
```

y cuando hagas un display de precios, usas

```
money_format('%.2i', $precio);
```